# How to invoke a WFS service from command line?

Tags: wfs, getfeature

I've the following WFS GetFeature request...

http://map.sitr.regione.sicilia.it/ArcGIS/services/CART_2000/Numeri_Civici/GeoDataServer/WFSServer?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=CART_2000:NumeriCivici_88006_Modica&SRSNAME=EPSG:3004&

... and the response (that you can try ....),  give me a GML response that I can use in a GIS Desktop.

I need to invoke this, and several other services like it, from command line and save the responses in files: any suggestions (curl? wget? other?) and samples on how to do it?

Comment: Hint: when you test, add &MaxFeatures=2 to your request. You can save your time and resources of the server. Once everything works drop the MaxFeatures and read the whole dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save this response in a `gml` file you can do the following:

`curl http://map.sitr.regione.sicilia.it.... -o ~/Desktop/test.gml`

(I was not able to get your url to work)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried your suggestion using Cygwin but it gives me an error "-bash: -o: command not found" ..... The request it's quite "heavy": have you tried it in a browser? I'm using Chrome and it's working but you've to wait for the response

Comment: hmm, on OSX so not sure how it works on a non-unix environment. The `-o filename.gml` just stores the output. What do you get when you type `curl --help`

Comment: This works for me on Windows 7: `curl "http://map.sitr.regione.sicilia.it/ArcGIS/services/CART_2000/Numeri_Civici/GeoDataServer/WFSServer?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=CART_2000:NumeriCivici_88006_Modica&SRSNAME=EPSG:3004&MaxFeatures=2" -o test.gml`

Comment: I noticed that it can be important to put the full WFS URL in quotation marks, else the shell may misinterpret the command. E.g., 
`curl "http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/inspire/ps-natura2000/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=ps-natura2000:ProtectedSite&outputFormat=json" -o file.geojson`